# A way to do this without a lot of variables and casting?

Tags: c#, casting

Currently I have this code:

```
float tileX = (float)rectangle.X / (float)newTileSize;
float tileY = (float)rectangle.Y / (float)newTileSize;

int xOrigin = (int)Math.Round(tileX) * newTileSize;
int yOrigin = (int)Math.Round(tileY) * newTileSize;

// Same idea for the next 4 lines

float tileWidth = (float)rectangle.Width / (float)newTileSize;
float tileHeight = (float)rectangle.Height / (float)newTileSize;

int selectorWidth = (int)Math.Round(tileWidth) * newTileSize;
int selectorHeight = (int)Math.Round(tileHeight) * newTileSize;
```

The reason for the first two lines is because if I don't cast them as a float it does integer division and I was a floating point value instead so I can round it in the next two lines.

This code is fine *I guess* it just seems like there would be a better way to do it without so much casting. Just seems rather verbose if that makes any sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for

```
int result = (int)Math.round((float)n/(float)d) * d;
```

(assuming you are only interested in the intermediate values for this particular calculation)

Here's a test case with an alternative:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestModulo extends TestCase {

    private final static int d = 7;

    public void testModulo() throws Exception {
        for (int n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
            assertEquals("fails for " + n, f2(n), f1(n));
        }
    }

    private int f1(int n) {
        return (int) Math.round((float) n / (float) d) * d;
    }

    private int f2(int n) {
        return ((n + d / 2) / d) * d;
    }

}
```

You can solve your problem using only integer math.

Comment: Much obliged =)

Answer (score 1):

> The reason for the first two lines is because if I don't cast them as a float it does integer division and I was a floating point value instead so I can round it in the next two lines.

Well, you only need to cast one side to get a float as the return value.

```
float tileX = (float)rectangle.X / newTileSize;
float tileY = (float)rectangle.Y / newTileSize;
```

Because you are working with the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` type there is really no other way to go about it.  All of the properties are `int`s, and you need to perform floating point arithmetic, so a cast is required.  You could of course assign the `X` and `Y` values to a `float` first, but that doesn't save you anything.  This is very common when working with graphics in WinForms.